# Member Function Call and the C++ Object Model

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, this

Consider the below code that is designed to study how member functions calls are made and how it relates to C++'s object model:

```
struct A {
  int a_;
};
struct B : A {
  int b_;
  void f();
};
void B::f() {
  std::cout << "this\t" << std::hex << this << '\n';
}
struct C: B {
  int c_;
};
int main()
{
  C c;
  C* pc = &c;
  std::cout << "&c\t" << std::hex << pc << '\n';
  pc->f();
  return 0;
}
```

Based on the C++ object model, object `c` will have the object layout:

```
  -------
 | a_    |
 |------ |
 | b_    |
 |------ |
 | c_    |
  -------
```

And,

1. `B::f()` would be translated to `void f(B *const)`
2. `pc->f()` would be translated to `void f(pc + offset(b_))`, where `offset(b_)` represents the offset of sub-object `B` in `c`.

So, based on the above observations, the output should be:

```
&c     address_of_c
this   address_of_c + sizeof(a_) = address_of_c + 4
```

But what I'm getting is the same address for both (I'm using g++ 9.2):

```
&c      0xffffcc0c
this    0xffffcc0c
```

I'm not clear as to why? Can someone please explain?

FYI: Bjarne Stroustrup has an article written about this; more specifically, you can refer to section 4.2 (page 373):

https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/compsystems/1989/fall_stroustrup.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that it should be `pc + offset(b_)` rather than `pc + offset(B)`, i.e. the offset of the `B` subobject in `C`? If you look at your graphic, you can see that both the `A` and the `B` subobject begin at the top, at the same address as the `C` object does.

Comment: Note that the example in the link is different. It lets `C` inherit from both `A` and `B`.

Comment: The offset of the B subobject in C is address_of_c + sizeof(a_) = address_of_c + 4 = offset(b_).

Comment: True, in Bjarne's example, C inherits from both A and B. But how would that matter?

Comment: In your example the `A` subobject is part of the `B` subobject, so the `B` subobject starts with `a_`, not with `b_`. This is not the case in Bjarne's example where the `A` and `B` subobject are distinct parts of `C`.

Comment: Oh, got it! :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class C inherits only one class B. So you have

```
struct B
   ^
   |
   |
struct C
```

When an object of the class C was created the sub-object of the class B was placed in the beginning of the memory allocated for the object of the class C.

Within the object of the class B there is a sub-object of the class A.

You can imagine the placement of an object of the class C the following way

```
struct B b;
int c_;
```